# SoapUI: Extract value from ResponseAsXML

Tags: soapui

I'm new, so please be understanding. I need extract value from response, and I don't have idea how to do it. I receive response response as par below:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">if(jQuery) {
                        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                if(jQuery('form').length) {
                                        jQuery('&lt;input type="hidden" name="commandHash" value="d7316353-429a-49f6-8523-7366db8c6f30" />')
                                                .appendTo('form');
                                }
                        });
                }</script>
```

I need extract value of commandHash, in this case: "d7316353-429a-49f6-8523-7366db8c6f30". Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve your question by making the example a [mcve], removing the extraneous elements.

Comment: What you posted is html, not a xml, right?

Comment: Rao you are right, it is html. Do you have any idea how to extract this value?

Answer (score 0):

In your property transfer step:
Use Xpath:
substring-before(substring-after(/script[@type="text/javascript"],"value="),"/>")

result:**"d7316353-429a-49f6-8523-7366db8c6f30"**

Answer (score -1):

In SoapUI you used to get API response like in Json or XML , this is non of the case. This is front end coding. 
For This you may use selenium not SOAPUI.

But if you have some REST API returning response in JSON you may use following code.

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonAsText = '''[{"errors":[],"result":{"applicationId":"3b30276f-f7f0-4cbb-8407-ed5337273346","userIds":null,"userCount":0,"name":"Group 1","description":"Desc 1","id":"464eaddf-e4ae-4222-b927-bac73f11cf2e"}}]'''
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonAsText)
def result= json.result
result.each{
    println it."applicationId"
    log.info it."applicationId"
}
```

Comment: Incorrect, it is possible to get HTML in SoapUI. For example to perform logins before accessing REST-service.